# How to sort dataframe by timestamp

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

I need to sort the following dataframe by timestamp. I know it is quite simple, perhaps one line of code, but all my attempts with sort_values or sort index fail. I must sort the dataframe by the id and the timestamp. So here a snippet of the dataframe:

```
 id        timestamp        x_value
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:35 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:36 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:37 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:38 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:39 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:41 2
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:15 1 
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:42 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:14 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:05:12 2
2854    2018-01-03 00:04:47 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:04:48 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:04:49 1
2854    2018-01-03 00:04:51 2
2854    2018-01-03 00:04:52 1
.
.
.
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:25 3
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:22 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:20 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:18 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:16 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:14 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:12 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:10 3
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:07 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:05 3
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:02 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:00 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:41:58 3
3245    2018-01-02 16:41:55 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:41:53 3
3245    2018-01-02 16:41:50 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:40:51 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:42:45 2
3245    2018-01-02 16:40:49 3
.
.
.
```

For every id I would like to have the date (days) sorted from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. The timestamp is inconsistent, so there are some missing timestamps but this should not be a problem in general. I need this because after this sort I will calculate the difference from the x rows and therefore I need a correct sorted timestamp, otherwise I would get wrong results. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'timestamp'])
```

Comment: @Maik, would you mind updating/validating this question please?